# Is drawing to the canvas optimized based on what's already there?

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

If I draw an image to the canvas and the pixels end up being mostly the same as what's already there, will this be faster than if I draw an image where all the pixels end up changing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately no, everything drawn to canvas is drawn using compositing ([Porter-Duff](https://drafts.fxtf.org/compositing-1/#porterduffcompositingoperators)) and blending rules regardless of what already is there before it (the same math is applied).

There is some form of dependency though as the existing content may influence the look on the final outcome of these operations, but not in a performance sense. Say various blending modes, global alpha, and of course compositing modes themselves etc.

The cost of checking what to draw and not would most likely outweight the cost of just drawing the content, and it would need to implement a somewhat complex mechanism to consider the various methods that can be used to draw - ie. not so useful for performance.

A browser vendor *may* chose to optimize for specific cases, but in general and regardless of existing content: everything passes through blending mode, composition and finally alpha blending with the background, at context level - this produces the bitmap used for the next step (or that we can extract as an image). Then something similar at element/DOM level so that the canvas and its content blends in with the rest of the page/DOM content, but where the alpha channel can be considered in a special way:

One exception in regards to performance, also in general, is when the browser need to composite and alpha blend the canvas element itself with the background (ie. everything behind the element). If the alpha channel is disabled for the canvas element, the browser can optimize this step which gives us a little more performance to draw from.

To disable the alpha channel for the 2D context you simply pass in the option:

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d", {alpha: false});
```

Comment: I'm really without knowledge on this matter ; isn't there some pre-multiplying thing going on with drawImage ? Also, does this mean that drawing full opaque is the same as blending different alpha values ? (I can get that differences are so tiny that nobody cares, but no difference at all sounds weird to me).

Comment: @Kaiido you probably have the final alpha-blending in mind. If there is a alpha channel the browser must composite it (at element level) with the underlying graphics, but if one isn't present this step can be skipped (e.g {alpha:false} in the context options) but it still need to composite the incoming source graphics including the alpha channel on the canvas itself (context level). The premultiplying step moves the opacity to the color components using multiplication (which causes rounding errors in some cases) but this is not necessarily done internally as the channels can be kept separate.

Comment: The premulitplication happens with getImagedata/putImageData. I am not entirely sure why this is necessary as the raw bitmap could have been dumped as "straight" (ie. no premultiplication) and premul. usually is used to *remove* an alpha channel completely to create a matte instead (where opacity level for each component is made to represent what would have been its alpha level). I haven't dug too deep into why they have chosen this way though, but for the context itself the porter-duff is always applied (except with clearRect, and blending always uses source-over) then alpha-blending.

Comment: I had in mind fill an opaque rect (e.g `#000`) over any content vs fill an semi-transparent one (e.g `rgba(0,0,0,.5)`). IMM the first one would take less calculations (even if they're done on the GPU) than the second one. Same for filling a fullSize rect vs graphics with a lot of antialiasing to produce. But thanks for those clarifications.

Comment: It makes sense but the problem is that the value of the alpha channel is always considered via the operators, incl. the one from the global alpha (f.ex w/ source-over, Fb = 1 – αs, col: co = αs x Cs + αb x Cb x (1 – αs) / a: αo = αs + αb x (1 – αs) even if alpha=1 it affects one of src/dst). That being said, it's of course possible that a browser vendor has chosen to optimize for special cases, but this could easily become a two-edged sword f.ex. in cases where most of the graphics contains some transparency or global alpha is <1 more often than not, or blending modes are used extensively etc.

Comment: * as to pre-mul: the last push to screen must of course be premultiplied since no monitor actually has an alpha channel, but all steps before that can hold separate channels.

Answer (score 1):

The two actions will take exactly the same amount of time, because they are both doing the same action. The result of the pixels does not change the speed of how long it will take to execute the code :)

It doesn't matter if the pixels change or not, the pixels **refresh** either way.